# Can I pass a signed seed to std::mersenne_twister_engine

Tags: c++, c++11, random, types

Consider

```
auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
          (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
std::mt19937 rd {ms};
```

`ms` is of type `std::chrono::system_clock::rep` which is signed. `std::mt19937` will call `std::mersenne_twister_engine(ms)` but its parameter type `result_type` is unsigned.

Is there an issue with this? [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) says it is undefined:

> result_type | The integral type generated by the engine. Results are undefined if this is not an unsigned integral type.

Comment: I read that as the result of a mt19937 that does not use an unsigned type as its `result_type` is undefined.

Comment: So, your question is if undefined results are an issue?

Comment: What @Nathan said. Also note you can always use legal `static_cast` from signed to unsigned types of the same or smaller sizes.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Is `ms` implicitly casted into an unsigned by `std::mersenne_twister_engine`? I'm not really worried about undefined results, I want to make sure I'm passing the right value to `std::mt19937`

Comment: casting from a signed to unsigned is defined behavior.

Comment: Ok I figured that was the case and nothing undefined would happen because it was from signed to unsigned. Thanks alot